# How can I update properties at run time from a distributed configuration property source in Micronaut

Tags: micronaut

I've created a ConfigurationClient which loads properties from Azure App Config during the bootstrap phase. This works correctly and my classes annotated with @ConfigurationProperties get the proper values from the distributed configuration property source.

When configuration properties change I receive a message (over service bus) and I want to update those properties and also update my configuration classes which use them.  I've tried emitting a RefreshEvent() but that doesn't cause the property source to be loaded again.  I've also tried setting the key and value for the property in the RefreshEvent but that doesn't update my Configuration class. I've also tried to call ApplicationContext.refresh() but, while that does reload the properties and recreate the configuration classes, that causes my server to become unresponsive.

What is the proper way to update properties and their subsequent configuration classes which rely on them when a property value changes at run time?

Comment: "I've tried emitting a RefreshEvent() but that doesn't cause the property source to be loaded again" - Is the class in question marked with `@Refreshable`?

Comment: I have tried to mark the configuration property with @Refreshable but that doesn't update the property source, unfortunately.